# "In March this year" or "last March"?

Tags: prepositions, time

Can I say

> I left Moscow in March this year.

or just

> I left Moscow last March.

Is it correct?

Comment: The interpretation of "last", in this sense, is highly variable.  If you say "last March" in April folks may suspect either the prior month or 13 months ago.  But in November it's generally taken to mean 8 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

*When did you leave?*

***In March,***

or (when a few months have elapsed)

***Last March.***

Both of these answers are common and clear (although 'last March' suggests 'a while ago' and so can be ambiguous if spoken too closely (eg. in April, May or June) to the moment referred to, as described in @Hot Licks' comment.

> *The interpretation of "last", in this sense, is highly variable. If you say "last March" in April folks may suspect either the prior month or 13 months ago. But in November it's generally taken to mean 8 months ago.*

"*I left Moscow in March this year*" would usually be used only as some kind of clarification.  For example

*"When did you leave?  It was in March 2015 wasn't it?"*

*"**No, I left Moscow in March this year**".*

Comment: Conversely, if you wanted to emphasize that you left during the March _before_ the most recent March, you might say that you left "in March of last year".